# ListView images just not showing up. Why (Drooping my head in shame that I have to ask)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview

I am trying to display images in a WinForms ListView that is in details view mode, but images are just not showing up.

I have added a SmallImageList (and a large one for good measure, added images to them, added my items to the ListView, but when I set the ImageIndex nothing happens. Images do not show up. I have also tried using the ImageKey.
Edit: I have added columns to the ListView.

I feel like an idiot that I have to ask about this, but I must be doing something wrong. Any steps I am missing?

Thanx much.

Comment: OK, I just dug myself a nice little whole in the ground. From here, I can let everybody know, in a sheepish voice, that I was being an idiot, so apparently my feeling was justified while asking the question.

Some how, I am tempted to give many reasons - but I'll refrain, the ListView lost it's reference to the ImageList (SmallImageList). It works now.

I marked kicsit's answer as the answer as he is the only one that tried to help and at least he got me going over everything systematically again.

Comment: I think you are too hard on yourself. Shit happens. How else would us programmers still have any work left to do? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you added any columns to the listView? I followed your steps and the only extra thing to do was to add a column to the Columns collection of the listView.

Comment: did this response solve your problem? do you still need help?